# Getting the sum of numbers

Tags: laravel

Answer has many rates:

**Answer Model:**

```
public function rates()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rate'); 
}
```

Rates table:

```
id answer_id user_id  rating
1   3          1       5
2   3          2       8
```

How do i get the specific answer with sum of rating?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you have two classes Answer and Rate. Also, there is hasMany relationship from Answer to Rate named 'rates'.

So for the sum of ratings of a specific answer, you can call 'sum' method from 'rates' relationship on 'Answer' model.

```
$answer          = App\Answer::find(1);
$sum_of_rating   = $answer->rates->sum('rating');
```